# How to implement/do the keycloak sso login in a custom provider/endpoint

Tags: java, single-sign-on, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm trying to implement a provider/cusotm endpoint in order to have the keycloak sso login feature among the keycloak realm apps without having to login via the keycloak login page,

I followed an answer that I found here with almost the same question, I achieved getting the sso or login cookies but still the sso login not working (I'm half sure that the server configurations are correct since the sso login works fine when I login via the keycloak login page)

so I will share the custom provider that it is giving me the login cookies

```
package com.custom_authinticator.keycloak;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.jboss.resteasy.spi.HttpRequest;
import org.keycloak.authorization.util.Tokens;
import org.keycloak.common.ClientConnection;
import org.keycloak.events.Errors;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.RealmModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserSessionModel;
import org.keycloak.protocol.LoginProtocol.Error;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken;
import org.keycloak.services.ErrorResponseException;
import org.keycloak.services.managers.AppAuthManager;
import org.keycloak.services.managers.Auth;
import org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager;
import org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager.AuthResult;
import org.keycloak.services.resource.RealmResourceProvider;
import org.keycloak.services.resources.Cors;
import org.keycloak.sessions.AuthenticationSessionProvider;
import org.keycloak.utils.MediaType;

public class CookiesProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {

    private KeycloakSession keycloakSession;

    public CookiesProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.keycloakSession = session;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("validate")
    public Response sso(@Context final HttpRequest request) {
        try {
            // get token and validate it
            System.out.println("[+] from the execution of the custom provider");
            final HttpHeaders headers = request.getHttpHeaders();
            final String authorization = headers.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
            if (authorization == null) {
                System.out.println("[!] did not find token in authorization it is null!");
                throw new ErrorResponseException(Errors.INVALID_REQUEST, "Invalid access token", Status.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            System.out.println("[+] authorization " + authorization);
            final String[] value = authorization.split(" ");
            final String accessToken = value[1];
            final AccessToken token = Tokens.getAccessToken(accessToken, keycloakSession);

            if (token == null) {
                throw new ErrorResponseException(Errors.INVALID_TOKEN, "Invalid access token", Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
                // return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
            }

            // retrieve data
            final RealmModel realm = keycloakSession.getContext().getRealm();
            final UriInfo uriInfo = keycloakSession.getContext().getUri();
            final ClientConnection clientConnection = keycloakSession.getContext().getConnection();

            final UserModel user = keycloakSession.users().getUserById(token.getSubject(), realm);

            final UserSessionModel userSession = keycloakSession.sessions().getUserSession(realm,
                    token.getSessionState());

            
            AuthenticationManager.createLoginCookie(keycloakSession, realm, user, userSession, uriInfo,
                    clientConnection);
            
            ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.OK);
            responseBuilder.entity("Authentication successful");
            // return responseBuilder.build();

            System.out.println("[+] everything fine ");
            System.out.println("[+] finishing the request " + request.getHttpHeaders().toString());
            return Cors.add(request, responseBuilder)
                    .auth()
                    .preflight()
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "OPTIONS")
                    .allowedOrigins("https://eduflix3.krugerschool.edu.ec")
                    .build();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("an error ocurred sending an empty response " + exception.getMessage());
            return Response.noContent().build();
        }

    }

    @OPTIONS
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("validate")
    public Response preflight(@Context final HttpRequest request) {
        System.out.println("[+] preflight request is being processing " + request.getHttpHeaders());
        return Cors.add(request, Response.ok("", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .auth()
                .preflight()
                .allowedMethods("GET", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedOrigins("https://eduflix3.krugerschool.edu.ec")
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public Object getResource() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

So as I mention I'm getting the 4 cookies in the response as headers, but what should I do next, why it is not working do I have to do any additional step that I'm missing?

the desired behavior is logging into the app A with credentials, then have the ability to login into app B without credentials SSO.

both apps are configured correctly since the behavior is flowing correctly when logging via the keycloak login page.

thank you in advanced.

and I'm sorry if it is a basic question but I'm new to the keycloak world.

I've tried to implement the mentioned provider above in order to active the sso login, what I expected to happen was logging in the app A get the sso cookies through the cookies-provider and sign in the app B with the sso.
what I got was the cookies in the response without activating the sso login.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).